# css functionality for body tag works without body tag in html file

Tags: html, css

Below is the code that my style.css file contains

```
body{
    background-color:pink;
    font-size: 130%;
}
```

The code that my style_placement.html file contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Style Placement</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css"> 

<style>

h2 {color:maroon}

</style>
</head>

<h1>Style Placement header</h1>
<p>This is heading one</p>

<h2>Subheading 1</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex et similique cupiditate dignissimos delectus nulla dolore, eos dolorum quidem excepturi, facere non repellat accusamus, atque? Id voluptate eos et accusantium.</p>
<h2>Subheading 2</h2>
<p style='text-align:center'></p>

</html>
```

Here I am not even using body tag in html file but styling for that tag has been applied. Can anyone please help me to know what is going on behind the scene ?
Below is the screenshot of how my output looks like in web browser
[image]

Comment: even though you omit adding the `body` tag it will be added automatically for consistency. If you inspect your page you will see your body tag among others. But i guess it's not recommended to do it this way as not all browsers might behave the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start and end **tags** for the `body` element are explicitly optional according to [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element).

They can be inferred from the content around them. The element is still created even if the tags are not there.

> Tag omission in text/html:
>
> - A body element's start tag can be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not ASCII whitespace
>   or a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a
>   meta, link, script, style, or template element.
> - A body element's end tag can be omitted if the body element is not immediately followed by a comment.

This has always been the case. See, for example, [the HTML 4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3):

> The bulk of the HTML DTD consists of the declarations of element types and their attributes. The `<!ELEMENT` keyword begins a declaration and the `>` character ends it. Between these are specified:
>
> - The element's name.
> - Whether the element's tags are optional. Two hyphens that appear after the element name mean that the start and end tags are mandatory.
>   One hyphen followed by the letter "O" indicates that the end tag can
>   be omitted. **A pair of letter "O"s indicate that both the start and
>   end tags can be omitted.**
> - The element's content, if any. The allowed content for an element is called its content model. Element types that are designed to have no
>   content are called empty elements. The content model for such element
>   types is declared using the keyword "EMPTY".

[and](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1)

> ```
> <!ELEMENT BODY O O (%block;|SCRIPT)+ +(INS|DEL) -- document body -->
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The browser is handling "dirty" html. It's not recommended to rely on it, since not every browser is handling in the same way.

[Some further info](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)